# Javascript : Check array element contains element from another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs

I have below array -

```
Array(12)
[
{username:"abc" , userpid:"M123"},
{username:"xyz" , userpid:"T234"},
{username:"mnp" , userpid:"L678"}
.
.
]
```

I have another array as -

```
Array (6)
    [
    {projectname:"corporate" , projecttype:"oil" userpid:"M123"},
    {projectname:"corporate" , projecttype:"oil" userpid:"K123"},
    {projectname:"corporate" , projecttype:"oil" userpid:"P123"},
    .
    .
    ]
```

Here , I wanted to filter out all the elements from first array whose userpid is not in second array. Eg. userpid M123 is present in second array thats why output -

```
[
{username:"xyz" , userpid:"T234"},
{username:"mnp" , userpid:"L678"}
]

I tried with - 

array1.some(x=>x.userpid!=(array2.filter(y=>y.userpid)))
```

But this is giving syntax error.

Comment: you are comparing a string (`x.userpid`) with and array (the return from `.filter()`

Comment: Try, `array1.filter(el =>  array2.every(f => f.userpid !== el.userpid));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```js
const arr1 = [
{username:"abc" , userpid:"M123"},
{username:"xyz" , userpid:"T234"},
{username:"mnp" , userpid:"L678"}];

const arr2 = [
    {projectname:"corporate", projecttype:"oil", userpid:"M123"},
    {projectname:"corporate", projecttype:"oil", userpid:"K123"},
    {projectname:"corporate", projecttype:"oil", userpid:"P123"},];

const result = arr1.filter(item => !arr2.some(v => item.userpid === v.userpid));

console.log(result);
```